# tqdm printing a new line when double progress bars are used

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

How to generate this problem:

```py
Python 2.7.18 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 23 2020, 22:42:48) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tqdm import tqdm
>>> for i in tqdm(range(10)):
...     for j in tqdm(range(5)):
...             import time
...             time.sleep(0.5)
... 
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|###################################################################| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  2.00it/s]
100%|#################################################################| 10/10 [00:25<00:00,  2.51s/it]
>>>
```

Is this intended by design? 
How can I avoid this problem? (I want to see just two lines which indicate 100%)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `position = 0` and `leave = True` parameters.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
for i in tqdm(range(10), position = 0, leave = True):
    for j in tqdm(range(5), position = 1, leave = True):
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

TWO WAYS

1: Create a label for inner loop (only one bar is shown but you know where your inner loop is)

```
with tqdm(range(10), desc="outer_loop") as pbar:
    for i in pbar:
        for j in range(5):
            pbar.set_postfix(inner_loop=j, refresh=True)
            import time
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

2: for 2 bars(only for notebooks): you might need to update your `tqdm`

In addition to tqdm features, the submodule provides a native Jupyter widget (compatible with IPython v1-v4 and Jupyter), fully working nested bars and colour hints

[DOCS](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#ipython-jupyter-integration)

```
from tqdm.notebook import trange, tqdm
from time import sleep

for i in trange(10, desc='1st loop'):
    for j in tqdm(range(5), desc='2nd loop'):
        sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: 1. is good especially when we iterate a lot!